# Crunch Debug Logging

Tags: logging, apache-crunch

Anyone who has used the Crunch pipelines knows that nothing is actually performed until the `pipeline.run()` or `pipeline.done()` method is called. Traditionally in most languages, we can put log statements to print out intermediate variable values, but with Crunch this is not possible because of the pipeline behavior. Is there a way/workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the debug and log statements inside your DoFn, MapFn, FilterFn functions which are logged during the execution of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it by getting `logger` and using it inside my doFn.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...

public static class MyDoFn extends DoFn<Integer, String> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyDoFn.class);
    ...

    @Override
    public void process(Integer input, Emitter<String> emitter) {
        ...
        logger.info("hello");
    }
}
```